# Compare 2 Lists of same sobject and store the unique records in a list

Tags: apex, list, sobject, id-comparison, unique

I have 2 `List<Sobject>` one contains `existingRecordsList` and other `updateRecordList`.

`existingRecordsList  = (Account:{abc__c=a0o7a000,xyz__c=a0o5r000, id =a0o5r000002GaHhAAK})`

`updateRecordList =  (Account:{abc__c=a0o7a000,xyz__c=a0o5r000},{abc__c=AVjN4AAL, xyz__c=2GaHhAAK})`

How can I compare these two lists and get unique record and to insert?
The problem what I face here is `existingRecordsList` has Id field and `updateRecordList` doesn't have Id in it.

Comment: For us to help you best, you'll need to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve. How are you getting `existingRecordsList` and `updateRecordList`? Please share more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only difference is really that the records in the existing list have an Id, then the solution here is really simple.

- Iterate over the existing records

  - Use `.clone()` (the first argument controls whether or not the Id is kept, and that defaults to false)
  - Put the cloned record into a set (let's call it `existingSet`)
- Put your non-existing records into a set (let's call it `newSet`)
- `newSet.removeAll(existingSet)`
- Now `newSet` only contains the records that don't appear in `existingSet`

Sets "hash" the data that's given to them, and the implementation of that hash method that SObjects have uses data from all of the populated fields (there's also an "equals" method so you could do `obj1 == obj2`). That's really handy (and also really fast) for comparing two things of complex types.

The only real gotcha here is that text-like fields end up being "compared" in a case-sensitive manner. `Account(Name = 'ABC123')` and `Account(Name = 'abc123')` would not be equal to one another. If you put those into a `Set<Account>`, your set would have a size of 2 instead of 1.